# ReportViewer: How to load report as an embeddedresource in another assembly using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, embedded-resource, reportviewer2008

I'm not really sure how to go about this. I created a generic class to open reports up for my application. The reports are contained in another DLL that is not referenced as an embedded resource though.

If I reference the DLL I can just do:
`Viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "SomeLibrary.ReportName.rdlc";`

However, since I'm not referencing the DLL I figure I have to get the report via reflection. This is where I'm stuck. I'm really not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this by reading the RDLC and returning the Stream.

```
public void PrepareReport(IAppReport report)
{
   Viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(report.GetStream());
}
```

With a bit of reflection I am able to pull that Stream object.

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to read the report as stream from the dll

Comment: I don´t know what is "IAppReport", that is a bad answer, this is the correct solution: 

System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream streamReport = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProjectOrAssemblyName.Reports.Report1.rdlc");

reportView1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportView1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(streamReport);

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream streamReport = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProjectOrAssemblyName.Reports.Report1.rdlc");

reportView1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportView1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(streamReport);
```